# Some "Storm Soul" questions

Tags: dnd-4e, sorcerer

I've created a Storm Sorcerer using Character Builder and I've got a question about "Storm Soul". It is described in "Class/Other features" section and states the following: "Resist thunder and lightning and pierce thunder and pierce lightning with your spells. End your resistance to gain +4 to all defenses."

So, I've got several questions regarding to it:

1. Where did "Storm Soul" come from? Is it just a benefit of storm sorcerer build?
2. Do I understand correctly that I can get rid of resistances and get +4 to all defenses till the end of encounter? Isn't it a kind of imbalance?
3. If yes, can I switch resistances/defenses whenever I want or there are some restrictions?

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Nice question, +1. If you haven't, I do recommend the [Tour], and when you get 20 rep, feel free to check out [Chat]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer your questions in order here.

1. Storm Soul is a class feature based on your selection of Storm magic. So yes, it's a feature of your storm sorcerer build.
2. The defense boost *only* lasts until the end of your next turn. And your resistance doesn't come back until you rest. So you trade resistance for the whole rest of the encounter for at most a full round of improved defenses. This may or may not be a good trade, it depends on the encounter. It's also important to note that it's a Power Bonus which means it does not stack with most other temporary buffs.
3. No. You can't flip them on and off like a light switch. There are two important things to reiterate on this point. First is that there is a definite trigger to ending the resistance and beginning the defensive bonus. That is being hit by an attack. The second is that once you swap, you're ability to resist is gone (as is your ability to penetrate resistance with your spells) until you rest.

It's important when building a character with the character builder to read the entire entry for the class you are building. If you have a DDI subscription it's all outlined [here](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/class.aspx?id=128). If you do not, but have access to your books, it is mostly contained in PHB2, the Storm Sorcerer is outlined in Arcane Power (p 26).